# Get Model Metadata from its class name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm aware that we can access model meta data using

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => Model, Model.GetType());
```

What I'm looking for is a way to access model metadata just using it's class name, without it's instance (maybe something like ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(Model.GetType())). Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need an instance in order to access the metadata of a type:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders
    .Current
    .GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(SomeViewModel));
```

And if all you have is a string representing the type name you could load the type from this string:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders
    .Current
    .GetMetadataForType(null, Type.GetType("AppName.Models.MyViewModel"));
```

Comment: `Type.GetType("AppName.Models.MyViewModel")` always return null, but `Type.GetType("AppName.Models.MyViewModel, AppName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")` returns the correct type. Thanks for the tip!