# Accessing DataAnnotations AdditionalMetadata in code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am struggling to find a simple answer to this question, hopefully someone out there can help?

I have a system using MVC3 code first and EF4.1.

I have a number of models and I am trying to override DbContext.SaveChanges to provide an audit facility.

There are certain high volume columns that should be excluded from the Audit.

I had hoped that I could use the AdditionalMetadata tag like so...

```
public class User : IAuditable
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [AdditionalMetadata("IgnoreAudit", true)]
    public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; }
}
```

and then in my audit code use something like...

```
bool AuditThis = ModelMetadata
   .FromLambdaExpression(dbEntry.Property(propertyName), null)
   .AdditionalValues("IgnoreAudit");
```

to determine whether to log the change or not.

Obviously this code fails as it was taken (and changed!) from a view.

My question is.  Can the ModelMetaData be read outside of a ViewContext or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the pointer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675473/304170) but I needed the slightly different

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders
    .Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, objType, propertyName);
```